# Python 3 - Convert 2-digit Integers to and from 2 character Hex Equivalent

Tags: python, integer, hex, byte

I have researched this and while I could find some methods to convert a string consisting of a 3-digit integer to a string consisting of its 2-digit hex equivalent, I did not find a way to convert the 2-digit-hex string back into the original 3-digit integer.

For example, I would like to convert "015" to its 2-digit hex equivalent "0F" and vice versa.

Another example: "123" to "7B" and "7B" to "123".

I would prefer separate methods for these two conversions, rather than 1 function that can take either type of string and return the other.

```
# Method I'm currently using to convert int to hex:
myHex = str(format(int(myNumber), '02x'))
print("Integer " + myNumber + " converted to " + myHex)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which part of that specifically are you struggling with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
def two_digit_hex_to_three_digit_integer(hex):
    return str(int(hex, 16)).zfill(3)
```

**Explanation:**

`int(hex, 16)` will convert your two-digit hex number into an int of base 10. Then, this will be converted to `str`, and it will be filled with up to 3 zeros to satisfy the condition you said of three-digit integer.

**Usage:**

```
>>> two_digit_hex_to_three_digit_integer('7B')
'123'
>>> two_digit_hex_to_three_digit_integer('0F')
'015'
```

Comment: `int` doesn't require the `0x` prefix; `int("7B", 16) == 123`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks, I didn't know that, I just updated my answer.

Comment: This worked great.  The zfill part was especially useful in case I wanted to convert to a 2-digit integer rather than 3-digit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

1) build in hex method

```
hex(int('123')) --> '0x7b'
str(int('0x7b', 16)) --> '123'
```

if you do not want '0x' part:

```
hex(int('123'))[2:] --> '7b'
str(int('7b', 16)) --> '123'
```

or :

2) using fstring

```
def str_to_hex(my_str_num):
    return f'{int(my_str_num):02x}'

def hex_to_str(my_hex):
    return f'{int(my_hex, 16):>03}'

print(str_to_hex('015'))
print(hex_to_str('0f'))

print(str_to_hex('123'))
print(hex_to_str('7b'))
```

output:

```
0f
015

7b
123
```

Comment: The part about removing the "0x" was really helpful.  I may go back to using hex() instead of format() after reading your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For `base-10` to `base-16` conversion you can harness `str` formatting following way:

```
def convert_dec_to_hex(value):
    return "%X" % int(value)
print(convert_dec_to_hex("123")) # 7B
```

uppercase `X` gives `ABCDEF` and lowercase `x` gives `abcdef` so

```
def convert_dec_to_hex(value):
    return "%X" % int(value)
print(convert_dec_to_hex("123")) # 7b
```

Comment: Interesting technique.  Thanks for clarifying the difference in using upper and lower case.  How would you handle converting hex back to dec?

Comment: @gnorman: so far I know there is not string formatting accepting hex number and giving dec number. In such case I suggest using `int` with second argument `16` as shown in others answers. As side note that `int` accepts as `base` (second argument) any number from `2` to `36`, so you could use it also for reading number written in any base from that range.